# Ionic cards constant height

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2, ionic3

I'm showing some ion-cards in slides and the height of the cards varies depending on the content size. How to make it constant?

code:

```
<ion-col *ngIf="types && types.length" no-padding>
  <ion-slides slidesPerView="4">
    <ion-slide nowrap *ngFor="let item of types">
      <ion-card (click)="select(item.type)" style="height: 100%">>
        <ion-label padding-top text-center text-wrap class="text4bl">{{ item.name }}</ion-label>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
</ion-col>
```

result image:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can set the fixed height of ion-slide like below

```
ion-slides{
    ion-slide {
      height: 200px;
      width: 100% !important;

      ion-card{
        height: 180px;
        width: 100%;
    }
  }
}
```